# How to repeat AsyncTask after itself complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using class extends Asynctask to download data form webservice. To prevent the data loss and request time out, I'm trying to repeat the asynctask and read data every 100 rows. But the looping error and never run the task :

**function to repeat the task :**

```
public void executeCustomer(String vSpvId){
    String vURL;
    int vloop = 1;

    while(notStop){
       vURL = Routines.URL_CUSTOMER + "?vloop=" + String.ValueOf(vLoop) + "&vsupvid=" + vSpvId;
       Log.d(TAG, vURL);
       vCustomerAsyncTask = new CustomerAsyncTask();
       vCustomerAsyncTask.execute(vURL);
    vloop++;
    }
}
```

**task to download data :**

```
private class CustomerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showProgressBar(Routines.WAIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... vURL) {
        String vASPXText = Routines.getASPXText(vURL[0]);
        return vASPXText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String vASPXResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(vASPXResult);

        try{
            if((vASPXResult.length() == 0)||(vASPXResult.contains("masalah"))){
                vDialogBox.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Routines.DATABASE_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                throw new NullPointerException(Routines.DATABASE_ERROR);                
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w(TAG, Routines.DATABASE_ERROR);
            vDialogBox.dismiss();
            showDialogBox(Routines.WARNING, Routines.DATABASE_ERROR);
            return;
        }
        vDialogBox.dismiss();

        notStop = parsingCustomer(vASPXResult);
    }
}
```

**function to parse data :**

```
private boolean parsingCustomer(String vASPXResult){    
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, vASPXResult);
        if(vASPXResult.indexOf("C@`") == 0){
            // function to parse data
            // return true to read next data from webservice
            return = true;
        }else if (vASPXResult.indexOf("F@`") == 0){
            // function to parse data
            // return false to stop read data from webservice
            return = false;
        }
    }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, Routines.DATABASE_ERROR);
        showDialogBox(Routines.WARNING, Routines.DATABASE_ERROR);
    }   
}
```

My problem is how to repeat the asynctask when it complete download the first data and then repeat  it self to do the next URL parameters. When I check in the logcat the looping is always runs but the task never done. So, how to make it can run dan repeating the asynctask.

Comment: If I read you correctly, there is no need to use for example 10 AsyncTask download 10 URLs sequently. In your case, simply construct and prepare 10 URLs and pass a list of URLs into a single AsyncTask, then in doInBackground() method, properly implement your for loop to iterate and process URLs in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a static counter and call the AsyncTAsk

like this

```
if(counter<desiredCount){


 vURL = Routines.URL_CUSTOMER + "?vloop=" + String.ValueOf(vLoop) + "&vsupvid=" + vSpvId;
       Log.d(TAG, vURL);
       vCustomerAsyncTask = new CustomerAsyncTask();
       vCustomerAsyncTask.execute(vURL);
}
```

in AsyncTask's `post excecute`.. What currently you have done may not work coz you start one AsyncTask before other one even finishes...

Comment: But i don't know how many the rows, so i can't initialize the static counter and i think the static counter can't used.

Comment: at my parsing function, i use the unique code to initialize when the process will stop or running.
.....
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, vASPXResult);
        if(vASPXResult.indexOf("C@`") == 0){
            // funtion to parsing data
            // return true to read next data from webservice
            return = true;
        }else if (vASPXResult.indexOf("F@`") == 0){
            // funtion to parsing data
            // return false to stop read data from webservice
            return = false;
        }
    }
......

Answer (score 0):

We can't execute AsyncTask two or more times.So,every time we create instance in local only. Like`new MyTask().execute(url).` Avoid the global declaration of async task instance. And another thing we can execute Async task multiple times using [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) class,which has also backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use to invoke it again like a regressive form `name.excuteTask()'

Comment: finally, i found the solution...
Just call the task again with new parameter in post execute until stop condition. Like recursive function...

Comment: @PaijoRX : Cool! thats what. you got it. But make sure your stop condition wont be much lengthy. And check whether it affects your applications instrumentation Handler.